# Python-docx table 'list index out of range'

Tags: python-docx

I tried to use Python access a table in docx file using Python-docx package, but got 'index out of range' error even the table have more rows/columns, see code & error in the image
[image]

Comment: I found that the error is raised when a cell contains "Field" content. No walkaround so far.